# I want to scramble an array in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, random

I want PHP to randomly create a multi-dimensional array by picking a vast amount of items out of predefined lists for n times, but never with 2 times the same.

Let me put that to human words in a real-life example: i want to write a list of vegetables and meat and i want php to make a menu for me, with every day something else then yesterday.

I tried and all i got was the scrambling but there were always doubles :s

Comment: Does each day have to have a random number of food items? I'd like to know more about what the proper output is.

Comment: No, each day has only one item of each section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Random != unique

You need to either:

a) create a list containing every possible combination and then randomly select and remove one

or

b) store your results so your random selection can be compared to previous selections.

Comment: I have already tried the second option you suggested, but i can't figure out how to compare the selections.

Answer (score 3):

Try the shuffle function https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Answer (score 1):

Use either [array_rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) or [shuffle()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php).